# Parse JSON array in Android without any array

Tags: java, android, json

I am new to JSON parsing, I know how to parse XML, but JSON seems compleatly different and confusing. I have this Array here:

```
{
    "domain": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "next_page_id": null,
    "url": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "short_url": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "author": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "excerpt": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "direction": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "word_count": 0,
    "total_pages": 0,
    "content": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "date_published": "2012-10-06 17:39:13",
    "dek": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "lead_image_url": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "title": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "rendered_pages": 1
}
```

I never used JSON before, but I always tought a JSON array would have a name. But this does not have one, so I can't do this:

```
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("ARRAYNAME");
```

Can somebody help me parsing this? 
thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a JSON Array. This is a JSON Object.
Json array is represented by `[]`
You can access these elements like so

```
String url = jObject.getString("url");
```

An array, for example would look like this:

```
{
    "domain": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "next_page_id": null,
    "url": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "array":
        [
            "element1",
            "element2"
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not array.Array contains elements of same type. Array is in [].  {} is object.
  [{},{}] 2 objects in array
Checkout this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html